# The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, https

I want to call a service as you can see :

```
public string ServiceHostName = "https://122.333.ir/InquiryService.svc";
        public InquiryService()
        {
            //ClientRequest = new WebClient();
            ms = new MemoryStream();
        }

        public Inquiryview Inquiry(string Plaque)
        {
            string result = "";
            using (WebClient ClientRequest = new WebClient())
            {
                ClientRequest.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
                ClientRequest.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                NetworkCredential credential1 = new NetworkCredential("1", "1");
                ClientRequest.Credentials = credential1;
                //result = ClientRequest.DownloadString(ServiceHostName + "/" + "2012-12-28" + "/" + "61" + "-" + "921" + "ج" + "25");
                 result = ClientRequest.DownloadString(ServiceHostName + "/Inquiry/2012-12-28" + "/" + Plaque);
            }

            var javascriptserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return javascriptserializer.Deserialize<Inquiryview>(result);
        }
```

But when i call the service i get this error :

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: AuthenticationException 
    Exception message: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)
```

My service certificate is a self sign ,so i downloaded the cert and add it in the trusted root certification as you can see but i get the same error :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution but not recommended

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
    (se, cert, chain, sslerror) =>
    {
        return true;
    };

            string ServiceHostName = "https://111.333.ir/InquiryService.svc";
        string result = "";
            using (WebClient ClientRequest = new WebClient())
            {
                ClientRequest.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
                ClientRequest.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                NetworkCredential credential1 = new NetworkCredential("1", "1");
                ClientRequest.Credentials = credential1;
                //result = ClientRequest.DownloadString(ServiceHostName + "/" + "2012-12-28" + "/" + "61" + "-" + "921" + "ج" + "25");
                result = ClientRequest.DownloadString(ServiceHostName + "/Inquiry/2012-12-28" + "/" + "11-365ب12");
            }

           // var javascriptserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to implement this [callback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback?view=netframework-4.7#System_Net_ServicePointManager_ServerCertificateValidationCallback).

`Service​Point​Manager.​Server​Certificate​Validation​Callback`

This will enable you to get more details about the **exact** certification failure.

You can look at the [SslPolicyErrors](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/SecureProtocols/SslStream.cs,dcab16068caa4a83) enum to see the exact failure reason

```
public enum SslPolicyErrors
{
    None                          = 0x0,
    RemoteCertificateNotAvailable = 0x1,
    RemoteCertificateNameMismatch = 0x2,
    RemoteCertificateChainErrors  = 0x4
}
```